# Normal map (not quite right) outline

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

[image]

Im not really sure why the outline of the anvil shows up on the normal map.
does anyone know what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

The outline you worry about just caused by setting Bake Margin to 16 px.

[image: bake margin]

As said in manual for [Render Baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/bake.html):

> **Margin**
>
> Baked result is extended this many pixels beyond the border of each UV “island”, to soften seams in the texture.

This value should depend on margin of unwrapped UV map - not be more.